# Passed ArrayList in an Intent but No Changes Were Made?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

sorry if this is a really obvious question. In a nutshell, I'm passing an arraylist from my `TshirtParadiseActivity` to `ShopActivity`. In `ShopActivity` I pass the arraylist to the `Adapter` class which creates listeners for checkboxes so they modify the arraylist when checked.

I can see changes made to the original arraylist inside `ShopActivity`'s onDestroy() method. However, once that activity is gone, and I return to the `TshirtParadiseActivity` I have an empty list again even though I had previously added to it in `ShopActivity`.

How can I make the changes to my arraylist persist between activities? I included my code below:

TshirtParadiseActivity.java

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.tshirtparadise;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TshirtParadiseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mSexy0;
    private Button mCheckOut;
    private int POOR=0;
    private ArrayList<Tshirt> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Tshirt>();
    private static final int requestCodeShop=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tshirt_paradise);
        mSexy0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sexy0);
        mCheckOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout);

        mCheckOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
               //ARRAYLIST IS EMPTY
               for (int i=0;i<shoppingCart.size();i++){
                   System.out.println("you bought a " + shoppingCart.get(i).getTitle() +
                           " for $" + shoppingCart.get(i).getPrice());
               }
           }
        });

        mSexy0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = ShopActivity.newIntent(TshirtParadiseActivity.this,0,shoppingCart);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

ShopActivity.java

```
public class ShopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView shirtRecyclerView;
//    private ShirtAdapter shirtAdapter;
    private int mQuality;
    TshirtAdapter teeAdapter;
    private List<Tshirt> teeShirtList;
    private static ArrayList<Tshirt>shoppingCart;
    private static final String QUALITY = "com.bignerdranch.android.tshirtparadise.muchquality";
    private static String CART = "com.bignerdranch.android.tshirtparadise.cart";
    private static final String BUY = "com.bignerdranch.android.tshirtparadise.buy";

    public static Intent newIntent(Context context, int quality,ArrayList<Tshirt>shoppingCart){
        //creates an instance of ShopActivity class
        Intent i = new Intent(context,ShopActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(QUALITY,quality);
        i.putExtra(CART,(Serializable)shoppingCart);
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Activities are presented to the user
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);
        TShirtCabinet cabinet = new TShirtCabinet();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        mQuality = bundle.getInt(QUALITY);
        //to transform serializable to arraylist, use getSerializable(String name)
        shoppingCart = (ArrayList<Tshirt>) bundle.getSerializable(CART);

        teeShirtList = cabinet.getList(mQuality);
        shirtRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.tshirt_list);
        shirtRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ShopActivity.this));
        teeAdapter = new TshirtAdapter(teeShirtList,shoppingCart);
        shirtRecyclerView.setAdapter(teeAdapter);
    }
}
```

TshirtAdapter.java

```
public class TshirtAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TshirtAdapter.ShirtHolder>{
private String TAG = "TshirtAdapter";
private List<Tshirt> teeList;
private Context mContext;
private static ArrayList<Tshirt> shoppingCart;

public TshirtAdapter(List<Tshirt> teeShirts,ArrayList<Tshirt>cart){
    teeList = teeShirts;
    shoppingCart = cart;
}
@Override
public TshirtAdapter.ShirtHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View viewHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tshirt,parent,false);
    return new ShirtHolder(viewHolder);
}
public class ShirtHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //render the view, don't add data yet
    private TextView title;
    private CheckBox bought;
    private ImageView preview;
    private TextView price;
    public ShirtHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tshirt_title);
        bought = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tshirt_checkbox);
        preview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tshirt_picture);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tshirt_price);
    }

    public void bindShirt(final Tshirt tee){
        title.setText(tee.getTitle());
        price.setText(tee.getPrice());
        bought.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn,boolean isChecked){
                if (btn.isChecked()){
                    shoppingCart.add(tee);
                    Log.d(TAG,"adding tee " + tee);
                }
                else {
                    shoppingCart.remove(tee);
                    Log.d(TAG,"removing tee " + tee);
                }
            }
        });
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            preview.setImageDrawable(mContext.getApplicationContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue));
        }
        else {
            preview.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue));
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ShirtHolder shirtHolder, int position){
    Tshirt t = teeList.get(position);
    shirtHolder.bindShirt(t);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return teeList.size();
}

public ArrayList<Tshirt>getShoppingCart(){
    return shoppingCart;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put an object into an `Intent` and send it to another `Activity`, for the most part you will wind up getting a *different* instance of that object in the new `Activity`. The list may come through with all the same values in it, but it's a different list as far as the program is concerned.

If you want to see the changes made on the second activity reflected in the first, you should make use of activity "results". In the first activity, start the second activity by calling `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. In the second activity, call `setResult()` before calling `finish()`. Then, back in the first activity, handle that result by implementing `onActivityResult()`, and update your list there.

Comment: thank you, do you know why its a different instance of the object in the new activity?

Comment: @st4rgut, you need to study core android arch to figure that out.

Comment: When you transfer an object using the `Serializable` interface, it makes a copy of the object (new instance). So `i.putExtra(CART,(Serializable)shoppingCart);` is going to send over the data needed to make a *copy* of `shoppingCart`, but it won't refer to the original instance.